# PHP Curl Does Not Show Response

Tags: php, curl

I have added this basic login page to server for testing curl form submitting:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        
        if($email == "email@gmail.com"){
            if($password == "123456"){
                echo "Correctamundo!";
            }else{
                echo "Wrong pass";
            }
        }else{
            echo "Wrong Email";
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="">
            <input type="email" name="email" value="">
            <input type="password" name="password" value="">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

So if the email equals to `email@gmail.com` && the password was `123456`, the **Correctamundo** message appears on the page.

Now with curl at another file I've added this:

```
<?php
$data = array(
    "email" => "email@gmail.com",
    "password" => "123456",
    "form" => "submit"
);

$ch = curl_init("http://sitename.com/login.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Allow Redirections
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); // Making a POST request
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt'); // COOKIE-jar: To save data for cookie created for login process
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // TRUE means Don't just echo output the data instead we can store the Request response in some variable

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
?>
```

Now as you can see I have passed the correct credentials as `$data` array. But when I load the page, I don't get the **Correctamundo** message as success message.

So why is that? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The password and email are wrong in the code you wrote. `"login[password]" => "email@gmail.com"`

Comment: @MostafaNZ Good catch! I have fixed that and now only shows the form itself and the response still unavailable...

Comment: @MostafaNZ It looks like it is not submitting the form cause I pass incorrect credentials, the form appears ....

Comment: The form will always appear regardless of your credentials. If there's any message it would be before that (but outside the html document, which is not ideal- check the raw response via View Source in case your browser decided not to show it). Btw there is also no logic in your form to show a message when the email address doesn't match

Comment: @ADyson I have added another `else..` condition to check the correction of email but I don't know why no message appears with both wrong credentials and correct credentials. Please would you help me with this...

Comment: Did you also check the raw response as I mentioned?

Comment: Also you can do some basic debugging  - in the login file, add `var_dump($_POST);` as the first line of code, and see what the script thinks was submitted to it

Comment: @ADyson Yes I checked the raw resources and nothing was there except the html form data

Comment: So what does the var_dump show?

Comment: @ADyson If I `var_dump($_POST)` with EMPTY form fields I get this: `array(3) { ["email"]=> string(0) "" ["password"]=> string(0) "" ["submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" } Wrong credentials`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246504/discussion-between-nagidi-and-adyson).

Comment: `"as you can see I have passed the correct credentials as $data array"` - No, you submit a field named `form` with a value of `submit` rather than submitting a field name `submit` with some value...

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I thought the word `form` here means the form element. So you mean I should pass `"submit" => "submit"` ?

Comment: that would work... or even `"submit"=>"banana"` - the name of the element is `submit` which is the param that you test in `isset($_POST['submit'])`

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Yes finally worked out! Thank you man <3